# Convert date to double with date before 1970

Tags: date, swift3, converters

How can convert date in swift to seconds/milliseconds/no matter - to double value, when date is before 1970? (when date after 1970 - its easy with `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates before 1970 are represented by a negative `Double` (aka `TimeInterval)`

```
let earlierDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: -200000000) // August 31, 1963 5:26
```